# How to install bower packages in angular fullstack generator?

Tags: angular-fullstack

How to install bower packages in angular fullstack generator? where to install and how, any file changes needed?

Comment: Which version of angular fullstack are you using ?

Comment: @amanpurohit so much thanks for your reply, i am using the latest one (https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack) as I just ran the yo angular-fullstack command like last week

Comment: all I wanted to do is to use packages in my front end like angular slickCarousel...I tried to install at client folder, then when i run gulp serve at the project folder (with both client and server), the server cannot be started due to .eslintrc-brower.json missing, etc

I tried to install at project folder, but then it can't load the modules, like the server could start but nothing can be loaded as it cannot find the modules e.g. slick carousel, jquery

Comment: So the latest version of angular-fullstack does not have a bower file. The frontend dependencies are also installed via npm. You need to find an npm module for the package that you want to install.

Comment: May I know from your experience, when the npm module says need to put these
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css">
    
    <script src="../bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script> 
    <script src="../bower_components/slick-carousel/slick/slick.js"></script> 
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-slick-carousel/dist/angular-slick.min.js"></script>

Comment: Do I just change bower_components to node_modules? as the docs in the npm website also tells me to install via bower..

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-slick-carousel I am so confused as when I found its npm module, it says I have to install via bower

Comment: Yes, just check that the path should be correct by looking into the node modules once and then replace.

Comment: @amanpurohit thanks so much! I am trying it:)

Comment: @amanpurohit may I know have you seen this error with the generator please? as I checked the path already, it still returns this error..

Error: Cannot read config file: /Users/car/Documents/apps/client/components/jquery/.eslintrc-browser.json
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/ca/Documents/app/client/components/jquery/.eslintrc-browser.json'

Comment: I am not sure about this one.

Comment: @amanpurohit thank you:)